# Limit serialization of nested collections to only show IDs in C# API MVC 4 with Entity Framework 4

Tags: c#, .net, json, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4

I am using C#'s MVC 4 API and Entity Framework 4 with auto generated Models and Controllers.
I have a parent-child relationship that I am serializing to JSON.
My relations are serialized just fine but I would like to show only the ids of the nested children instead of the whole objects.

This is the JSON response I am currently getting.

```
[{
    "ID": 1,
    "NAME": "PARENT1",
    "CHILDREN": [{
        "ID": "1",
        "NAME": "CHILD1"
    },{
        "ID": "2",
        "NAME": "CHILD2"
    }]
}]
```

And this is what I'd like to get.

```
[{
    "ID": 1,
    "NAME": "PARENT1",
    "CHILDREN": [1,2]
}]
```

These are kinda the models I am using.

```
public partial class PARENT
{
    public PARENT()
    {
        this.CHILDREN = new List<CHILD>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string NAME { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CHILD> CHILDREN { get; set; }
}

public partial class CHILD
{
    public CHILD(){}

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string NAME { get; set; }
    public int PARENT_ID { get; set; }
}
```

My controller method.

```
// GET api/Parents
public IEnumerable<PARENT> GetPARENTs()
{
    return db.PARENTS.AsEnumerable();
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated since I am not sure what I should be looking for.
I'm fairly new to EF and .NET's MVC and this seems like something that should be pretty easy to do.

Thank you all very much in advance.! :)

Comment: You should be using ViewModel that represents the structure of your JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think all you need is a simple LINQ:

```
IList<PARENT> parents; // I assume you have a list of PARENT fetched from DB

var results = parents.Select(
      p => new 
      { 
          ID = p.ID, NAME = p.NAME, 
          CHILDS = p.CHILDREN.Select(a=>a.ID).ToList() 
      }).ToList();

return Json(results);
```

Comment: Do you happen to know if there is a way to modify the controller on the previous post to return a list of anonymous objects that could work with your answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

More complex way is to use your own custom [media formatter](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/media-formatters) that uses custom xml serialization.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a reference this is another way I figured out to do this.
Most of you won't approve the use of dynamic but since I wanted to use this in multiple relations and not specify each time the type of the object it worked like a charm.

```
public class CollectionOfIds : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        IList collection = (IList)value;
        List<int> ids = new List<int>();
        foreach (var item in collection)
        {
            dynamic itemCollection = (dynamic)item;
            ids.Add(itemCollection.ID);
        }
        serializer.Serialize(writer, ids);
    }
}
```

After I am just decorating the model attribute as such...

```
public partial class PARENT
{
    public PARENT()
    {
        this.CHILDREN = new List<CHILD>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string NAME { get; set; }
    [JsonConverter(typeof(CollectionOfIds))]
    public virtual ICollection<CHILD> CHILDREN { get; set; }
}
```